# how to make kuberbetes external can access the redis cluster？

Tags: redis, kubernetes

I built a redis cluster in kubernets. The redis cluster was maliciously accessed inside kubernetes, but when I tried to access the redis cluster outside kubernetes, the following problem occurred, Redis can only read or write to the currently connected redis.When I use `cluster nodes` to view redis cluster information, it can be displayed correctly.

This is my statefulset.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster-node
spec:
  serviceName: "redis-cluster-svc"
  replicas: 6
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: redis-cluster-node
        app: redis
    spec:
      hostNetwork: false
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrykey
      containers:
      - name: redis-cluster-node
        image: redis-cluster:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 6380
        env:
        - name: MODE
          value: "cluster"
        - name: REDIS_CLUSTER_REPLICAS
          value: 6
        - name: LOG_LEVEL
          value: 0
        - name: REDIS_PORT
          value: 6380
        - name: MY_POD_IP
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: status.podIP
        - name: MY_POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: MY_POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

This is my service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster-svc-np
  labels:
    name: redis-cluster-svc-np
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6380
    targetPort: 6380
    nodePort: 30079
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    name: redis-cluster-node
```

[image: Cluster internal access redis]

[image: Cluster external access redis]

So, how to make kuberbetes external can also access the redis cluster？

Answer (score 0):

In your service manifest, change the `type` to `LoadBalancer` and add the `loadBalancerSourceRanges` field to restrict access to certain set of IPs. CIDR notation is used for listing the IP address ranges.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-cluster-svc-np
  labels:
    name: redis-cluster-svc-np
    app: redis
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 6380
    targetPort: 6380
    nodePort: 30079
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    name: redis-cluster-node
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
    - 100.100.100.100/32
    - 10.1.1.1/24
```

Make sure you add the cluster IP range to allows Redis accessible from inside the cluster.